# Some astronomer could tell me why Meeus calculations (Astronomical Algorithms, 1998) use Julian Centuries instead of Julian Days?

Tags: astropy, astronomy

In their algorithms, all calculations that use Julian periods to compute positions from a reference epoch (such as J2000.0) use Julian centuries and not Julian days. Who knows the reason for this? Thank you.

Comment: Unless you are talking about a specific API/library that uses those calculations, I'd suggest you move your question to https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, Arthur, very kind. He was unaware of that place. I will do so. All the best.

Comment: P.S. in fact I was unaware that StackOverflow was part of a larger stackexchange community network. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question on topic for StackOverflow